# Adding AO render pass in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, compositing

I am compositing a modeled sea scene in AE. Here's what I have:

[image]

Adding in my AO layer gives nice strong shadows as shown:
[image]

However it also covers my blue sea (primarily an AE 4color background)....

How can I keep the AO benefits to the shadows on my critters, but also keep my background?

As rendered, I have alpha, color pass with alpha, AO and depth (which is driving AE lens blur). I can render anything else needed.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Let's try to make it work. :D

1) Place 'Alpha' layer above 'Ambient Occulsion',

2) Change setting in 'TrkMat' of the layer 'Ambient Occulusion' to 'Luma Matte'

*if Luma Matte is not working, try with 'Alpha Matte' (I'm not sure about your alpha layer :))*,
[image: trkmat]

3) Precompose 'Alpha' + 'Ambient Occulsion' layers *ctrl+shift+c*,

4) Set precomposed layer to 'Multiply' Mode.

Done!

Comment: Absolutely perfect! It was Luma matte that worked, as you suggested... And the solution worked without precompose, and this probably points to something I still do not understand about AE: What additional benefit does precomp offer beyond just stacking things where they are? But THANK YOU !

Comment: Precomposing is just collapsing layers into one, in this example I recommend precomposing, for cleaner workflow. _becouse propably you are not going to modify alpha channel in AO_ :D